# is it possible when using count in MySQL to get the individual record ID's

Tags: mysql

```
ID      domain
1      yahoo.com
2      yahoo.com
3      gmail.com
4      gmail.com
```

Let's say I have a statement like this

```
SELECT ID, domain, COUNT(*) as total FROM table WHERE blah = 123 GROUP BY domain
```

Is it possible to get each individual `ID` number, but while in a `COUNT`? I need to count the records but I also need the individual record ID numbers as well. I am pretty sure this is impossible but ultimately I need the totals and ID's

```
domain       total
yahoo.com     2
gmail.com     2
```

but also have the ID's (1,2 for yahoo.com) and (3,4 for gmail.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID) AS IDs, domain, COUNT(*) as total 
FROM table 
WHERE blah = 123 
GROUP BY domain
```

Comment: OMG I really did not think this was possible and it also puts it in a pretty format!!! You are the man.